# Multiple XML-files, initialize?

Tags: android, xml, initialization, oncreate

Just got started with Android programming and i got a task where im supposed to fill in two textfields and then click a button for a new frame to come up with some more textfields.

I decided to change the contentView to a 2nd xml file i created when you click that button. However im not able to use the widgets inside that 2nd xml file until i change the contentview? I wanna add clicklisteners and so on which i cant on the buttons that arent visible yet..

Should i use another approach or am i just retarded?

Comment: Create another activity, start it with an intent. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, exactly what i was looking for! As i said im new to this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want everything to be in one Activity (which is supposed to represent a single screen), you can specify all your views in a single XML file, and set the visibility of the views you want hidden at first to `invisible` or `gone`. Then you can show them later. Since everything is in a single XML layout, you can access the Views even if they are not visible, but the user will not see them.

To set visibility in Java you use `view.setVisibility(int visibility)` where the integer is [`View.VISIBLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE), [`View.INVISIBLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE) or [`View.GONE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE).

Comment: Then i have to manually change the booleans everytime i change view? Sounds pretty lame to be honest but ill give it a try

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using [Fragments API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) .

Comment: You can use compatibility  package. It provides Fragments for API 1.6+, you can download it in sdk manager, sample project is also there.